# (abusing?) git workflow

Tags: git, workflow

Coming from Sourcesafe, I have primarely been using git as a major undo feature. I tend to 
work in the master branch, code happily away for some time, commit here and there and move on.

While I'm coding my brains out, I sometimes wish to drop what I'm doing right 
now and start working on another feature. I know I can start another branch right now but let's assume I'd like to keep working on master. I should have branched when 
I started working on the *previous* feature but that would have required me to plan ahead (at which I'm terrible btw).

I am pretty confident that what I need is possible with git, but I can't get my head 
around it. As a picture tells more than a thousand words, schematicly this is what I would like to do:

```
0--1 master

0--1--2 master

0--1--2--3 master

0--1--2--3 aBranch    
    \-4    master

0--1--2--3 aBranch    
    \-4--5 master
```

**Edit:** I should clear up that every number is a commit.

Comment: When I was new to git and got into similar situations, I found "gitk --all" to be very helpful for both seeing how the commits and branches are related, and also to do some operations on the GUI.

Comment: It wasn't so much the fact that I needed to see the relations visually (love gitk --all & tortoisegit to visualize things btw) but that I assumed for commit 1, 2 & 3 to be on branch *aBranch*, I should have *started* with *aBranch* while doing commit 1 (I hope I'm making sense to someone :). Now I realize how stupid that whas.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this is possible, and not hard. The short version: [`git branch aBranch`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-branch.html) to create the new branch, [`git stash`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash) to save any uncommitted changes, and [`git reset --hard 1`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset) to reset `master` to the commit you would like, and optionally `git stash pop` to apply those uncommitted changes to your current working copy, if they were intended for the new `master` branch.

Here's a full explanation, with diagrams so you can follow along. In the following, I will notate the current branch (HEAD) with a `*`.

```
0--1 *master

0--1--2 *master

0--1--2--3 *master
```

Create new branch `aBranch` pointing at the current commit:

```
$ git branch aBranch
```

```
0--1--2--3 *master aBranch
```

If you have any changes in the working copy that haven't yet been committed, save them with a stash (this is important, as `git reset --hard` will wipe away any uncommitted changes you have):

```
$ git stash
```

```
0--1--2--3    *master aBranch
         \- 4 stash
```

Now reset `master` back to the revision you want it at. I'm using `1` below as a placeholder; you may want to use the SHA-1, or something like `origin/master` if you want to reset it to the revision that the upstream `master` branch was at before you made your commits:

```
$ git reset --hard 1
```

```
0--1--2--3    aBranch
   \     \- 4 stash
    \-        *master
```

If you had uncommitted changes in your working copy that you stashed away, and you want to apply them to `master`, you can use `git stash apply` or `git stash pop` (`apply` will leave the stash recorded as a commit; `pop` will clean up the stash).

```
$ git stash pop
```

```
0--1--2--3 aBranch
   \-      *master (with stashed changes now back in your working copy)
```

Now you're on `master`, and reset to commit 1, exactly as you wanted to be. New commits will go to the `master` branch.

```
0--1--2--3 aBranch    
    \-4    *master

0--1--2--3 aBranch    
    \-4--5 *master
```

Note that if your working copy is clean (nothing reported by `git status`), you don't need the `git stash` command. If you wanted to apply your changes to `aBranch` instead of `master`, you would just use `git stash pop` the next time you switched back to `aBranch` and started working on it again.

One important point to keep in mind is that you should only edit branch history like this in your own private repositories, not public ones that other people could pull from. If you push this to a public repository that people are pulling from, then they'll have to rebase all of their changes, and it's best not to make them do that unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: Several good answers to choose from. I have taken the liberty to just select the first good answer that came around. Thank you all guys.

Comment: Brian, I've accidently clicked the downvote io the accepted answer icon. I can't seem to undo this (perhaps a git reset would help). Sorry about that.

Comment: I've edited it, so you should be able to change your vote now if you wish to (though, it looks to me like you've already done so).

Answer (score 3):

Sure, at this point:

```
0--1--2--3 master
```

Run the following commands:

```
git branch aBranch
git reset --hard 1
```

The [`git branch`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-branch.html) command creates a branch at the current HEAD (so "master" and "aBranch" refer to the same point, but "master" is still the current branch), and the [`git reset`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset) command winds everything back on the current branch ("master") to commit 1. Then you'll be here:

```
0--1--2--3 aBranch    
    \      master
```

Committing "4" at this point will give:

```
0--1--2--3 aBranch    
    \-4    master
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is easy to do in git.

When you've made commit 3 on master and you realise it should be on another branch you can just create a new branch based on the current position.

```
git branch aBranch
```

You can then wind master back to commit 1

```
git reset --hard <sha1_of_1>
```

and carry on working, making commits 4 and 5 as you would normally. They fork from commit 1 making a separate branch from `aBranch`.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [git-stash](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash).

Edit: If you need to go back further than HEAD, you can always do a [git checkout](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout) specifying the start point to get a new branch starting from any given commit in master.

Answer (score 0):

I know little about git, and struggle each time I have to do anything remotely non-trivial. I use Mercurial, where what you want is quite easy:

http://stevelosh.com/blog/2009/08/a-guide-to-branching-in-mercurial/#branching-anonymously

Comment: +1 sweet, especialy if you know I've tried mercurial too. I'm still kind of in between between git and mercurial but what the link describes to is exactly what I would need... in git :)

Comment: It's fairly trivial in git too. You just need `reset` and `branch` which are both in the list of common commands according to `git help`. I don't believe the guide you've linked to is particularly accurate in its comparison with git. With git you can detach your HEAD at any time. You are now on an 'anonymous' branch. Of course it's going to be more difficult to find than a named branch but both the reflog and `git fsck` will let you find old detached heads.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get in the habit of branching every time you start on a new feature.

That said, you can do this:

0 -- 1 -- 2 -- 3  master
     -- 4 -- 5   aBranch

You don't want to mess around with a branch's history - that's going to cause you many headaches.

Always develop on a branch, then merge back to master and commit to SourceSafe from there.

Comment: This isn't correct. You shouldn't ever push changes to a public repository that mess with a branch's history; but one of the big benefits of Git over other systems is that you can easily edit the branch history in your own local repository, which makes it easy to get a patch series really clean and understandable before sending it off for code review.

Comment: @Brian While editing history is occasionally useful, I think it’s better Git discipline to create a logical series of commits as you go, and to consider editing operations to be exceptional, not basic (with the possible exception of `git commit --amend`). I do sometimes build up a commit incrementally, but once I’ve done so, I pretty much treat that commit as immutable unless I made a gross error.